# Symfony Serializer - How to group array of objects?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to create XML file with 'groupped' elements, e.g. attributes.
I have sample object classes:
**Product**

```
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $attributes = [];

    // standard getter/setter for name

    public function getAttributes(): array
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function setAttributes(ProductAttribute $attributes): void
    {
        $this->attributes[] = $attributes;
    }
}
```

and **ProductAttribute**

```
class ProductAttribute
{
    private $name;
    private $value;

    // standard getters/setters
}
```

Now I'm creating `Product` object and serialize it with Symfony's Serializer:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('My product');

foreach ($arrayWithAttributes as $attr) {
    $attribute = new ProductAttribute();
    $attribute->setName = $attr['name'];
    $attribute->setValue = $attr['value'];

    $product->setAttributes($attribute);
}

$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$serializer->serialize($product, 'xml');
```

And I'm getting result:

```
    <item key="0">
        <name>My product</name>
        <attributes>
            <name>Attribute Name #1</name>
            <value>Attribute Value #1</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>Attribute Name #2</name>
            <value>Attribute Value #2</value>
        </attributes>
    </item>
```

but I'm expecting:

```
    <item key="0">
        <name>My product</name>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>Attribute Name #1</name>
                <value>Attribute Value #1</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
                <name>Attribute Name #2</name>
                <value>Attribute Value #2</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
```

How can I get this?
I was already tried with:

```
//Product.php
public function setAttributes(ProductAttribute $attributes)
{
    $this->attributes[]['attribute'] = $attributes;
}
```

but then I getting:

```
    <item key="0">
        <name>My product</name>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>Attribute Name #1</name>
                <value>Attribute Value #1</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <attribute>
                <name>Attribute Name #2</name>
                <value>Attribute Value #2</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
$attrArray = [];

foreach ($arrayWithAttributes as $attr) {
    $attribute = new ProductAttribute();
    $attribute->setName = $attr['name'];
    $attribute->setValue = $attr['value'];
    $attrArray[] = $attribute;

}

 $product->setAttributes($attrArray);
```

then in your entity

```
$this->attributes['attribute'] = $attributes;
```

Comment: In this case, I'll always override current value of `$this->attributes` and on `100` attributes result will be - `1`

Comment: yes, when iterating you can save them one by one in a array; then set them in your product at the end you iteration

Comment: Same result as `$this->attributes[]['attribute'] = $attributes;` (mentioned in question)

Comment: you just can't set your attributes every interation, all it will do is recreate the array attributtes over and over again...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this - I had to add `ArrayDenormalizer` for normalizers to support nested tree and change `Product` `$attributes` property setter. Finally it looks:

```
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $attributes = [];

    // standard getter/setter for name

    public function getAttributes(): array
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function setAttributes(ProductAttribute $attributes): void
    {
        $this->attributes['attribute'][] = $attributes;
    }
}

class ProductAttribute
{
    private $name;
    private $value;

    // standard getters/setters
}

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('My product');

foreach ($arrayWithAttributes as $attr) {
    $attribute = new ProductAttribute();
    $attribute->setName = $attr['name'];
    $attribute->setValue = $attr['value'];

    $product->setAttributes($attribute);
}

$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer());

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
$serializer->serialize($product, 'xml');
```

Comment: Just a side note. You can also use JMSSerializer bundle to make things simpler for yourself. An example can be found [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oxlj/validating-serialising-and-mapping-xml-request-to-model-classes)